# How to access form alias in Angular 2 to reset form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Angular2 I have a template with a `<form>` inside a bootstrap4 dialog. The form contains input elements:

```
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
   <form #heroForm="ngForm">
      <input ...>
   </form>
</div>
```

Note that the form gets the alias `heroform`.

As the input elements use validation, I want to call `heroForm.reset()` to clear all input and validation states when the modal hides.

Thus in the component, I hook up to this modal event:

```
$('#mymodal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e: any) {
   heroForm.reset(); <-- how to get this heroForm "instance"
});
```

But how can I access `heroForm` from there?

Comment: Where do you actually want to reset this, in component? Having a bit of trouble understanding. And why use jQuery? Couldn't you just use refer to the form and use `this.heroForm.reset()`? Maybe I'm stupid, but I am not really understanding this :P

Comment: Check this question, it resolves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575494/angular-2-formcontrol-reset-doesnt-work-but-resetform-does-but-typescrip/44575620#44575691