# Angular 2 FormControl.reset() doesn't work, but .resetForm() does (but typescript error)

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

In my Angular 2 form, I have the following typescript:

```
export class UserEditComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() userModel: IUserModel;
    @Output() onSave: EventEmitter<IUserModel> = new EventEmitter<IUserModel>();

    @ViewChild("userEditForm") userEditForm: FormControl;

    private userNameIsValid = true;

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
    }

    ngOnChanges (changes: SimpleChanges) {
        this.userEditForm.resetForm();
        console.log(this.userEditForm);
    }

    ....
}
```

and template html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #userEditForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveUser()" novalidate>
    ....
</form>
```

I tried using the .reset() function, but it did nothing.  The .resetForm actually resets the _submitted property of the form from true back to false, however, it gives me a TypeScript error `Property resetForm does not exist on type FormControl`.

First, is resetForm an actual function that works?  I can't seem to find any documentation for it... but it works and .reset() doesn't.

Second, how can I get rid of this TypeScript error?  Do I need to update my typings for Angular 2?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl there is no `resetForm`, if you get rid of that then the typescript error will be gone

Comment: Declare `userEditForm` as [**`NgForm`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) like this: `ViewChild("userEditForm") userEditForm: NgForm;`, so you can access `.resetForm()` method.

Comment: @developer033 That was what I was missing.  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `userEditForm` as [**`NgForm`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)like this:

```
@ViewChild("userEditForm") userEditForm: NgForm;
```

Now you can access `.resetForm()` method.

Comment: missing @ in ViewChild

Answer (score 1):

You should import NgForm from @angular/forms and try this.

```
OnClear(userEditForm: NgForm) {
  userEditForm.reset();
 }
```

Comment: That did it!  I should have used the type NgForm instead of FormControl.  Btw, there is a resetForm in NgForm.

Answer (score 0):

Add import:

```js
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";

ngOnChanges (changes: SimpleChanges) {
    /** add this **/
    form.reset();
    console.log(this.userEditForm);
}
```